# Collision bugs in corners of screen

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Okay so, when I test my code, the boundaries around the outside of the screen work quite well. It stops the box from going directly left, right, up or down. However, when I go against the left or right wall and then either go up or down, the box goes past the boundary and I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Code:

```
import pygame

*Initialize pygame*

pygame.init()

*Create screen*

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

*Caption and Icon*

pygame.display.set_caption("Runes")
icon = pygame.image.load("rune.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

*Player*

player_img = pygame.image.load("testcharacter.jpg")
player_x = 370
player_y = 480
player_x_change = 0
player_y_change = 0

def player(x, y, x_change):
screen.blit(player_img, (x, y))

running = True

while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_x_change = -0.1
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_x_change = 0.1
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_y_change = -0.1
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_y_change = 0.1
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if player_x_change == 0.1:
                    print("Right key still pressed")
                else:
                    player_x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if player_x_change == -0.1:
                    print("Left key still pressed")
                else:
                    player_x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if player_y_change == 0.1:
                    print("Down key still pressed")
                else:
                    player_y_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if player_y_change == -0.1:
                    print("Up key still pressed")
                else:
                    player_y_change = 0
    
    
    
    player_x += player_x_change
    player_y += player_y_change
    
    if player_x <= 5:
        player_x = 5
    elif player_x >= 730:
        player_x = 730
    elif player_y <= 5:
        player_y = 5
    elif player_y >= 532:
        player_y = 532
    
    player(player_x, player_y, player_x_change)
    pygame.display.update()
```

[Going to the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1xo0.png)
[Holding down the down arrow key from the left wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kq2J.png)

I've tried changing the boundary positions a little, but it has had no effect on it, the issue just moves with the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
if player_x <= 5:
    player_x = 5
elif player_x >= 730:
    player_x = 730
elif player_y <= 5:
    player_y = 5
elif player_y >= 532:
    player_y = 532
```

As the code is currently written, only one of the corrections in this chain of `if`/`elif`s can be reached. That's a problem if your player is trying to move diagonally off the corner of the screen.

To fix the issue, you need to allow the `x` and `y` corrections to both happen on the same frame. To do that, just change the second `elif` to be another `if`. Here's what that looks like, with an extra blank line thrown in for clarity:

```
if player_x <= 5:
    player_x = 5
elif player_x >= 730:
    player_x = 730

if player_y <= 5:
    player_y = 5
elif player_y >= 532:
    player_y = 532
```